# Generate xml element named 'properties' with StreamingMarkupBuilder

Tags: xml, groovy

I need to generate some xml that includes an element called "properties". When I attempt the following, I notice that groovy is trying to get the properties of my class, as evidenced by its call to `getSomething`. It should instead only generate an element named "properties".

```
class XMLGen
{
    public String getSomething() {
        println "Got something"
    }

    public String genXml()
    {
        def myProps = ['a':1, 'b':2]

        def xml = new groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind{
            rootTag{
                properties{ // ???
                    myProps.each{ prop ->
                        property(key: prop.key, value: prop.value)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
    }
}

println new XMLGen().genXml()
```

Output:

```
Got something
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><rootTag>
  <properties>
    <property key="a" value="1"/>
    <property key="b" value="2"/>
  </properties>
</rootTag>
```

How would I explicitly "tell" groovy to pass the method call on line (marked ???) to the markup builder?

(Asking this question and answering it myself as I couldn't find a solution for this anywhere, but eventually "guessed" the right answer)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to add "delegate" before "properties", as below:

```
delegate.properties{ // ???
```

You can also add a parameter to the `bind` closure and call `.properties` on it instead, like below:

```
def xml = new groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind{ smb ->
    ...
    smb.properties{ // ???
```